# using position absolute, relative and fixed together with a variable height header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am working on a new version of a layout for one of my current websites. I have set up the following example for as far as I have gotten: http://jsfiddle.net/ckdm1m7q/

html:

```
<body>
    <nav><ul><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul></nav>
    <header>
        <img src="http://rockstartemplate.com/headerdesign/banner_green.jpg" />
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="left_col"></section>
        <section id="right_col"></section>
        <main id="main_content">
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer>
        &copy; blah blah
    </footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    height:27px;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul, nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 27px;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

header img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
    display: block;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
}

#left_col {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 240px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #eee;
    overflow:auto;
}

#right_col {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 240px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #eee;
    overflow:auto;
}

#main_content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #666;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 240px;
    overflow:auto;
}

footer {
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I would like #left_col, #right_col and #main_content to only fill the viewport area available (100% - 27px - [*header*.height] - 20px) and be scrollable within that area.

This is difficult as the height of *header* will change on smaller resolutions.

Is this possible in pure html+css? And if so, how could I achieve it?

edit: To explain my aim a bit better:

1. #main_content needs to be scrollable without moving , #left_col, or #right_col.
2. #left_col and #right_col need to be scrollable individually, if they extend past the bottom of the viewport
3. *footer* can be moved to the bottom of #main_content if that makes things easier
4. *header* does not have to be visible upon scrolling down.